# Batch file cannot re-assign value in loop

Tags: batch-file

I want to make the batch file that checking the account information.

Within below codes, I need 2,3,4 line from "net accounts" command outputs, and each line needs the individual process.

For to do this, I use the 'cnt' variable, and increase to checking.

However, 'cnt' doesn't increase at #1.

Why this happened, and how to solve it?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
net accounts > accountInfo.txt

set cnt=0
echo """"""""""""""""""""""""""
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%G in (accountInfo.txt) do (
ECHO.%%G | FIND /I "mum">Nul && ( 

    SET var=%%~nH
    Set myvar=!var!
    set myvar=!myvar: =!

    echo %%G  !myvar!
    echo %cnt%

    set /A cnt+=1 ---------- here! #1
    ) || ( ECHO. )
)
echo """"""""""""""""""""""""""
ENDLOCAL
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using DelayedExpansion everywhere else in your code. Why not there as well?

Just change `echo %cnt%` to `echo !cnt!` and you should be fine.

Reason for that is that in batch blocks of code beeing surrounded by parenthesis are calculated at once. To see the updated value use DelayedExpansion as said above.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Not for that :) 4 eyes sometimes see more than 2 ;)